# Table not updated with Ajax and Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I ve been searching through other topics to find a solution for that but nothing .
I have form and i want to update the form input values when update button is clicked . The code that i using in Ajax is

```
$("#updateit").click(function() {

    var surname = $("#search_text").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var company_name = $("#company_name").val();
    var firm = $("#firm").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var town = $("#town").val();
    var tk = $("#tk").val();
    var country = $("#country").val();
    var telephone = $("#telephone").val();
    var fax = $("#fax").val();
    var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
    var web_site = $("#web_site").val();
    var visitors = $("#visitors").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
       $.ajax({
            url: 'update1.php',
            type: 'POST',
       data: {surname:'surname',name:'name',company_name:'company_name',firm:'firm',address:'address',town:'town',tk:'tk',country:'country',telephone:'telephone',fax:'fax',mobile:'mobile',mail:'mail',web_site:'web_site',visitors:'visitors',id:'id'} , 
dataType:'html',   
            success: function(data)
                        {           
alert(data);                        
                        }
        });
    });
```

The PHP file for updating values is this :

```
<?php
require('db.php');
include("auth.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
$id=$_POST['id'];
$surname =$_POST['surname'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
$company_name=$_POST['company_name'];
$firm= $_POST['firm'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$town= $_POST['town'];
$tk= $_POST['tk'];
$country= $_POST['country'];
$telephone= $_POST['telephone'];
$fax= $_POST['fax'];
$mobile= $_POST['mobile'];
$mail= $_POST['mail'];
$web_site= $_POST['web_site'];
$visitors= $_POST['visitors'];

$update="update base set surname='".$surname."', name='".$name."',company_name='".$company_name."',firm='".$firm."',address='".$address."',town='".$town."',tk='".$tk."',country='".$country."',telephone='".$telephone."',fax='".$fax."',mobile='".$mobile."',web_site='".$web_site."',visitors='".$visitors."' where id='".$id."'";
mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
$status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';

?>
```

Any Help appreciated

Comment: Tip: use serialize()  https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: What is error in console ? Did you try print_r($_POST); in your php file ?

Comment: The mysql_ interface functions are deprecated. New development should use either mysqli or PDO. The PHP code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Potentially unsafe values included into the SQL text must be properly escaped. A better pattern is to use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*.

Comment: print_r is getting these results 
    [surname] => surname
    [name] => name
    [company_name] => company_name
    [firm] => firm
    [address] => address
    [town] => town
    [tk] => tk
    [country] => country
    [telephone] => telephone
    [fax] => fax
    [mobile] => mobile
    [mail] => mail
    [web_site] => web_site
    [visitors] => visitors
    [id] => id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the following line in your AJAX request,

```
data: {surname:'surname',name:'name',company_name:'company_name',firm:'firm',address:'address',town:'town',tk:'tk',country:'country',telephone:'telephone',fax:'fax',mobile:'mobile',mail:'mail',web_site:'web_site',visitors:'visitors',id:'id'}
```

you're actually sending strings like `surname`, `company_name` etc. rather than the value of the variables. So remove those single quotes. It should be,

```
data: {surname:surname,name:name,company_name:company_name,firm:firm,address:address,town:town,tk:tk,country:country,telephone:telephone,fax:fax,mobile:mobile,mail:mail,web_site:web_site,visitors:visitors,id:id}
```

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_` database extensions, they were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: nope nothing it doesnt even return the alert(data) in ajax when before did

Comment: @Aristain *hmm*, that's because `mail` is not defined. See this line, `data: {..., mail:mail, ...}` in your AJAX request. You should have a variable named `mail`, like this: `var mail = $("#mail").val();`.

Answer (score 2):

the data sent through ajax is not correctly formed. It should be:

```js
var data = {'surname':surname,'name':name,'company_name':company_name .....}
```

rather than surname: 'surname'

Comment: nope nothing it doesnt even return the alert(data) in ajax when before did

Comment: you may follow these debugging steps: 1. use console.log to print out all variables captured from each dom. 2. add error: function(data){} and done: function(data){} to ajax 3. change the dataType from 'html' to 'text' for debugging 4.in PHP, use echo or var_dump to test all variables.